# How to use functions within crontab

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

My crontab has several similar calls where a script is called with a flock file, timeout, and output / error logs. I'd like to put this logic into a shared function that I just pass the script path and timeout length to. Is there any way to define a function within the crontab that can be used by all entries?

The best workaround I've found so far is defining my function in my .bashrc file, and wrapping every cron command with `bash -ic "..."` to make them run in an interactive shell, but this seems overkill, and means my crontab's functionality is linked to my .bashrc file. Is there no better way to use functions within the crontab?

Testing on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

---- Edit ----

Per the comments, here's an example entry in my crontab:

```
0 */4 * * * IFS=; output=$(flock -n /home/me/my_script.lock timeout 3600 python3 /home/me/my_script.py 2>&1 || if [ $? -eq 124 ]; then echo "`date '+\%s'`: Killed due to timeout"; fi); if [ "$output" ]; then echo $output; fi >> /home/me/logs/my_script.log 2>&1
```

...and the corresponding test function I put in my .bashrc file

```
test() {
        IFS=;
        output=$(flock -n test.lock timeout 300 python3 test.py 2>&1 || if [ $? -eq 124 ]; then echo "`date '+\%s'`: Killed due to timeout"; fi);
        if [ "$output" ]
        then
                echo $output
        fi
}
```

...the function of course being hard-coded just for testing, if used I would add parameters for the script path and timeout length per OP.

Hopefully this better explains the desire to use a function, as the whole IFS, flock, timeout, and 'killed by' pieces are all reused for each line (of which there are multiple dozen). If there's any better solution catered to this need, all suggestions welcome, otherwise the suggestion to just call my function as a separate bash script sounds appropriate.

Comment: It's difficult to help you if you don't show how your scripts and crontab look like

Comment: Why not just put the function in a wrapper-script along with your other scripts? `function /path/to/script timeout` is not much different to `/path/to/function-script /path/to/script timeout`

Comment: A crontab start programs (processes) according to a certain schedule. A function is not a process. It runs inside some process. Of course you can start a process (say, a bash script), which then invokes the function. Of course the question is why you are so eager to use a function .....

Comment: Example code added - the separate bash script sounds like an appropriate solution. I'll leave this open for today in case there are any changes from the example code.

Answer (score 0):

Put the function in a file and you can do

```
0 * * * * . /path/to/file; func_name arg1 arg2
```

Be aware thaat the default shell for the crontab is /bin/sh. If your function relies on bash features, set `SHELL = /bin/bash` in the crontab. See `man 5 crontab`